# Layer-List drawable as background does not completely fill its Android view

Tags: android, textview, layer-list

I have been working with a Layer-List drawable for some time now.

I am not really understanding why the drawable does not fit the dimensions of the Textview. **Only after I set android:background="some color"** and **android:drawableTop="@drawable/myxml_drawable"** is when ***I began to see the drawable was all over the place of this textview.***

First I just had:  **android:background="@drawable/myxml_drawable"** doing this will clip the top part of the drawable even though I matched the specifications of the size that was used in creating the xml drawable.

See the picture of the drawable below( purple arrow) and the textview has been colored black.

[image]

The only reason why the drawable looks centered in the background of this textview is cause I used paddingTop and paddingLeft to fix the appearance.

Here is how the textview is laid out in its constraintlayout

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/uppy_arrow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/grandstander_extrabold"
    android:gravity="bottom|fill_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/add_string"
    android:textColor="@color/purple_200"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/uppy_arrow"
    android:paddingTop="43dp"
    android:paddingLeft="9dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/my_image_view"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/t2"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/t2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.99"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    />
```

***How can I use this xml drawable as the background of this textview and make sure it fills the size of the textview as much as possible so that the text will be centered on it?***

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check the drawable itself. Make sure there is no inherent padding to it.Use vectors.
2. If you're using png or any other format makes sure the scaletype paramter is set to  a legit value like fitXY or centerCrop
3. To center the text inside the image.You can also have a imageview separately and superimpose your textview on it

Comment: The xml drawable has the android:top="some dp", android:bottom="some dp" , android:right="some dp" ANd android:left="some dp"  Do you think that its possible that is why the arrow is well inside the TextView?

Comment: The source is the problem then,, just see the preview of the vector asset when you create it

Comment: yes I figure out the source is the problem. It has to do with not defining android:top="some number", as well as android:left="1dp" and android:right="15dp" so the drawable is pushed to the right of its container way more than the left. I need to wrap this drawable in an XML bitmap  and use the android:gravity="center"  But Android studio says it can't find the resource of the Bitmap.

Comment: Can't you use the imageViewBehind TextView approach..i think you can play with the alpha a bit and it would give you much more flexibility and control

Comment: What I did was that the Layer-List Arrow was placed inside another Layer-List that I centered. And, now it shows nicely. In the new Layer-List I used android:top="10dp",  android:bottom="10dp", android:left="10dp" ,,  android:right="10dp"  .  I had tried to load the original Layer-List Arrow as an XML Bitmap but Android Studio kept on giving me ResourcesNotFoundException!